# Issue implementing line move up with Qt

Tags: qt, pyside, qplaintextedit

I've done a quick implementation of a move line up, in a class deriving `QPlainTextEdit`, but I have a weird issue.

The code works well, but the issue happen after an undo: cursor is not restored at the previous position in case the cursor was at the start of the line (and is restored on the next line).
If the cursor was at any other position on the line before the move, it is restored correctly.

Can you shed some light on this ? Thanks!

```
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore
from PySide.QtGui import QTextCursor
import sys

class MyTextEdit(QtGui.QPlainTextEdit):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyTextEdit, self).__init__()

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        key = event.key()
        if key == QtCore.Qt.Key_Up:
            mods = event.modifiers()
            if mods & QtCore.Qt.ControlModifier and mods & QtCore.Qt.ShiftModifier:
                cursor = self.textCursor()
                cursor.beginEditBlock()
                orig = cursor.position()
                cursor.movePosition(QTextCursor.StartOfLine, QTextCursor.MoveAnchor)
                n = orig-cursor.position()
                cursor.movePosition(QTextCursor.Down, QTextCursor.KeepAnchor)
                text = cursor.selectedText()
                if len(text) == 0:
                    cursor.endEditBlock()
                else:
                    cursor.removeSelectedText()
                    cursor.movePosition(QTextCursor.Up, QTextCursor.MoveAnchor)
                    cursor.insertText(text)
                    cursor.movePosition(QTextCursor.Up, QTextCursor.MoveAnchor)
                    cursor.movePosition(QTextCursor.Right, QTextCursor.MoveAnchor, n)
                    cursor.endEditBlock()
                    self.setTextCursor(cursor)

        return QtGui.QPlainTextEdit.keyPressEvent(self, event)

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
form = MyTextEdit()
form.setPlainText("""\
let zero f x = x
let succ n f x = f (n f x)
let one = succ zero
let two = succ (succ zero)
let add n1 n2 f x = n1 f (n2 f x)
let to_string n = n (fun k -> "S" ^ k) "0"
let _ = to_string (add (succ two) two)
""")
form.show()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: Can you give a minimal working example to see the behaviour?

Comment: @Ben: done. My guess is that it is only possible to restore back the cursor to it's original position through extra insert/delete of text. Will try this if it works.

Comment: hm it seems i am not completely understand the problem. So if you have 3 lines and the cursor is at the beginning of line 3 and you press Strg+Shift+Up then line 3 should be line 2 and line two should be line 3. The cursor then is supposed to be at the beginning of line 3 but is moving up as well?

Comment: It's the normal behavior that the cursor is moving with the line (see Sublime Text as a reference). The problem lies when I undo the operation, the cursor is not restored at the original position but one line down.

Comment: I could reproduce your problem but unfortunately i cant figure out what causes the cursor to jump one line down if the cursor is at the beginning of a line. What might help is to reimplement the behaviour of the undoStack. http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qundo.html

Comment: The exact same behaviour can be observed with Qt Creator. So it is obviously not a problem of PySide nor your implementation.

Comment: @Ben: Thanks for trying it out. I know about Qt Creator, I've checked it too. What I'm interesting in, is to understand the internals of Qt and why this is happening. I will try to redo it with Qt5 to see if the issue is still happening...

Comment: @Ben: btw I can't afford to migrate on Qt5, I'm stucked with PySide/Qt4 right now.

Comment: I ve tried it already using the latest Qt version (5.4) i thought about checking the source. Problem must ne somewhere in the UndoStack (internals) as you said.